# get the command line parameters from within a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to get the command line parameters used to invoke make utility inside a Makefile. Example:

```
make -C /some/folder -f someMakeFile.mk SOME_VAR=someValue
```

Inside someMakeFile.mk, I would like to get my hands on the following string:

```
-C /some/folder -f someMakeFile.mk
```

or

```
-C /some/folder -f someMakeFile.mk SOME_VAR=someValue
```

I'm not interested in SOME_VAR value, that is already well known. I'm interested in the rest of the command line switches for make utility itself (-C and -f).

The reason I'm asking is because I would like to slightly alter the behavior of someMakeFile.mk when certain cmd line switches are used. For example, I would like to return dummy values from complex macro definitions when make is invoked in dry-run mode, rather than do the actual work. This would speed up the TAB auto-completion in bash when you type make than TAB+TAB to show the list of targets.

Or, if this is not possible, is there a way (a variable or function) available for someMakeFile.mk to detect that is only a dry-run?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `MAKEFLAGS` variable to see if the first word contains an `n` (for dry run):

```
ifeq (n,$(findstring n,$(firstword $(MAKEFLAGS))))
  $(info in dry-run mode)
else
  $(info not in dry-run mode)
endif
```

Comment: inspecting $(MAKEFLAGS) is indeed the variable I was missing. Thank you!